# How to get command line application output to a variable in background in PowerShell 5.1?

Tags: powershell, zabbix, powershell-5.0, windows-server-2019, command-line-arguments

**SOLVED**

Thanks to @mklement0 's advice, I tried to get an exit code from rstcli64.exe:

- from cmd I get 0
- from zabbix-agent I get 3 (INVALID_DEVICE, according to manual)
  So, the culprit is not PowerShell, but rstcli64.exe exiting with an error in conditions: Windows Server 2019 and ran from PS script ran by zabbix-agent. I've updated rstcli from Intel's website and new version has the same syntax and works perfectly in new conditions.

**ORIGINAL POST**

I have Windows Zabbix Agent, which runs a PowerShell script, which runs a command line application, parses output and gives 1 or 0.

```
$states = C:\util\rstcli64.exe --information --volume 2> $null | select-string -Pattern "State:"

$notNormalStates = $states | Select-String -Pattern "Normal" -NotMatch
if ($states.Count -gt 0 -and $notNormalStates.Count -eq 0){
    "1"
} Else {
    "0"
}
```

This script worked on Windows Server 2012 R2, but after migration to Windows Server 2019 (with PowerShell 5.1) it began to output only 0.

This is a wave-particle duality situation: if I run this script from command line (User, Administrator, System - the same), it gives 1, because it receives the output from rstcli64.exe; and if zabbix-agent runs this exact script, it gets nothing from rstcli64.exe, thus gives 0.

So I guess the difference is that I run the script from an interactive shell and zabbix-agent runs the script from background.

And the question is: how do I get the output from a command line application in PowerShell 5.1 (Windows Server 2019), when run in background?

**MORE INFO**

If I just use this:

```
$states = C:\util\rstcli64.exe --information --volume
$states
exit
```

It shows a lot of data if I run the script in command line:

> --VOLUME INFORMATION--
>
> Name:              HDD_MIRROR Raid Level:        1 Size:
> 1863 GB StripeSize:        64 KB Num Disks:         2 State:
> Normal System:            True Initialized:       True Cache Policy:
> R
>
> --DISKS IN VOLUME: HDD_MIRROR --
>
> ID:                0-0-0-0 Type:              Disk Disk Type:
> SATA Disk State:             Normal

But if ran from zabbix - there's nothing:

> 6304:20201014:170446.686 EXECUTE_STR()
> command:'%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
> -nologo -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File "C:\util\intel_rst_raid.ps1"' len:0 cmd_result:''   6304:20201014:170446.686 Sending back []
> 8208:20201014:170446.687 End of collect_perfstat()

**MORE INFO**

It just does it with rstcli64.exe. With few other command line tools I get the same output when manually running script in cmd and triggering it from zabbix-agent. Again, only in PowerShell 5.1 in Windows Server 2019, so...

Comment: OK, thank you for that. But the main issue remains a secret.

Comment: Thanks, @real_sm. I have no explanation for your symptom, but I'd try capturing `C:\util\rstcli64.exe` stderr output in a file  (e.g. `2> errs.txt`), calling a different executable just to see if that works, echoing something _before_ the call to the external executable. However, there is no explanation for why no output at all is being captured, given that PowerShell sends _all_ output streams to stdout by default - unless zabbix collects stderr output separately (which PowerShell detects)?

Comment: Another aspect - though, again, it shouldn't really matter here and doesn't explain the symptom - is the PowerShell instance that zabbix runs the _32-bit version_ of PowerShell?

Comment: @mklement0 well, it gets interesting. With 2> redirection this happens: if I run script from command line, I get what I need in the cmd window, but in errs.txt I see this:

`C:\util\rstcli64.exe : 
C:\util\intel_rst_raid.ps1:2 знак:11
+ $states = C:\util\rstcli64.exe --information --volume 2> C: ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
0`

Comment: But if zabbix runs the same script - errs.txt is empty. :(

Zabbix runs 64 bit version of PowerShell, I explicitly run it with absolute path: "%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"

Comment: Re 64-bit: What matters is whether zabbix itself is 32-bit or 64-bit - 32-bit processes see a different directory as `%SystemRoot%\system32`. From a 32-bit process you'd have to use `%SystemRoot%\SysNative\` to access the 64-bit dir.

Comment: Re `errs.txt`: So stderr was definitely produced, but I can't tell from your comment what its actual content is - I only see the information added by PowerShell.

Comment: I see. Zabbix-Agent it also 64 bit. But, again, the same setup worked on Windows Server 2012 R2 (and works now on other machines). Also, I've mentioned in an edit to post, that I tried some other command line tool (zabbix_sender.exe) - and it works fine in any conditions. So I suppose there's something in rstcli64.exe, but what?

Comment: Yes, the stderr was produced, when I ran script from cmd. When run from zabbix - errs.txt is empty.

Comment: I've never used `rstcli64.exe`, so I can't be of help there. But note that there's also the added mystery of no output at all getting captured - unless zabbix captures stderr (from _PowerShell_'s errors in that case) as well. If you can inspect the process exit code, see if it is `1`: that would indicate that execution of the script failed fundamentally (if it even got to that point), due to a script-terminating error (loosely speaking, an unhandled exception).

Comment: @mklement0 I've got the exit code of rstcli by using `$lastExitCode`! In cmd it is 0 and from zabbix it is 3! So, definitely nothing to do with Powershell. Thank you! I will be researching that.

Comment: Has the user running the agent (service?) enough rights on the system?

Comment: @Nas yes, it runs under system. I've tried cmd under system - works perfectly. Somehow rstcli gives error code 3 when run from zabbix. I will add this to the post.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an issue with redirection and streams.  The information stream was introduced in 5.0 and Windows 2012R2 comes with 4.0.  Which might explain the different behavior.

[About_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7)

I'd play around with the redirection operators to see if you can get what you need piped to `Select-String`.  It might look something like:

```
$states = C:\util\rstcli64.exe --information --volume *>&1 | select-string -Pattern "State:"
```

This takes all streams and redirects them to the success stream, this way everything goes down the pipeline to `Select-string`.

I'd also advise you can make your RegEx a little more precise. Maybe `"^State:"` so you are capturing lines that start with "State:". Though I don't know if there may be preceding white space.

Comment: The RegEx is fine. If I output the $states variable, I receive a lot of "State:             Normal State:             Normal State:             Normal" in $states. If I run in cmd. But if zabbix-agent runs the same script - there is nothing.

"*>&1" did not help, the result is the same

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know enough about the executable to test on my own.  You might try `Start-Process` which has `-RedirectStabdardError` & `-RedirectStandardOutput` parameters.  Based on other comments that might be something to experiment with.

Comment: rstcli64.exe is Intel Rapid Storage Command Line Interface tool that outputs different info about RST controller and drives. you can download it from Intel website and run it even if you don't have Intel controller